# Django: Get first row from related table and show with main table query

Tags: django, django-models

The image table contains multiple images of a product. I want to bring an image column to match the product ID in the query set of the product table, which is the first image of the related product ID in the image table.

**Model:**

```py
    class Product(models.Model):
        product_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
        product = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    
    class Image(models.Model):
        product     = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
        image       = models.ImageField(upload_to= images_directory, validators=[FileExtensionValidator (allowed_extensions=['jpg', 'png'])])
```

**Product Table data:**

```
id  product_code    product
1   CHB1            xyz1
2   CHB2            xyz2
```

**Image Table data:**

```
id          image                                                   product_id
1           product/CHB1/CHB2.jpg                                   1
2           product/CHB1/CHB3.jpg                                   1
3           product/CHB1/CHB5.jpg                                   1
4           product/CHB1/CHB6.jpg                                   1
5           product/CHB1/CHB7.jpg                                   1
6           product/CHB2/Hc91885ca5dbb46249e7b835e13404244O.jpg     2
7           product/CHB2/H61a2825ba68948e0a2eac0fd23d2a26fK.jpg     2
8           product/CHB2/H71b69c050a0e4e3ca080f11bf12d5009P.jpg     2
9           product/CHB2/Hd34bc4633b7441f8a006d98db42af9ebO.jpg     2
```

**Raw SQL:**

```
select p.*, i.image from accpack_product p
join (select product_id, image 
      from accpack_image 
      group by product_id 
      order by id) i on p.id=i.product_id
order by p.id
```

**As I want:**

```
id  product_code    product       image
1   CHB1            xyz1          product/CHB1/CHB2.jpg
2   CHB2            xyz2          product/CHB2/Hc91885ca5dbb46249e7b835e13404244O.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want by the statement in the question is:
The first image of each distinct product

eg:
Image table:

```
product_id  |   image_id
1               1
1               2
1               3
2               4
2               5
3               6
```

The result which you want:

```
product_id |    image_id
1               1
2               4
3               6
```

If this is the case then the query would be:
The query is corresponding to PostgreSQL

```
images = Image.objects.distinct("product_id").select_related('product').order_by("product_id", "id")
```

This will get you the images queryset, Containing each row as the first image for each distinct product. Here `select_related` is used to optimize the query.
Each image object contains the product object from which product details can be fetched.

**Edit:** 
 For SQLite:

```
from django.db.models import Min
from django.db.models import Prefetch

image_ids = Image.objects.values("product_id").annotate(image_id=Min("id")).values_list("image_id", flat=True)
products = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch("images", queryset=Image.objects.filter(id__in=image_ids), to_attr='image'))
# The above statement results in two queries
for product in products:
    # work to do
    if product.image: # Check is required as list is returned
        # work to do with image
```

Here for each product, the image will be a list containing only one element(the first image)

```
product.image   # to_attr is set on Prefetch
# result: [<Image: 1>]
```

If you are fetching all the products (Notice the use of `all()` in products query) It'll surely gonna take a lot of time because of the db call(getting all the data in the memory) but the queries are limited to only two, Hence optimized.

Comment: It says: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend. I'm using SQLite.

Comment: @AbzalAli Can you check the answer I've edited it again. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Getting this error: Not Found: /products/[<Image: Image object (1)>]
[2021-05-31 01:01:14,133] log: WARNING - Not Found: /products/[<Image: Image object (1)>]
[31/May/2021 01:01:14] "GET /products/[%3CImage:%20Image%20object%20(1)%3E] HTTP/1.1" 404 21635

Comment: Hey, It seems the error is some URL you are trying to access.
The question is irrelevant with this part I suppose.
Question states about getting a query and not how to access it through any URL or converting it to model based viewset maybe.
It'll become a different question.

Comment: `product.image`  returning the `pk` of the image table. I need the value of the `image` field by `pk` from the image table.

Comment: It's returning a list(because of one to Many relation) but containing only one image i.e. the first one. Iterate over that and you'll get the image object from which you can get the image.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get your product object then u can get your image by related name:

```
image = Product.objects.get(pk=your_product_pk).images.last() # as id is the default ordering
# or you can do
image = Product.objects.get(pk=your_product_pk).images.order_by('id').last() # the ordering can be based on any field
# Or you can also do this  
image = Product.objects.get(pk=your_product_pk).images.all().latest('pk')
```

it gives you the last image of a product.

Comment: Can this query be done in any other way than parameters?